# Correlation function $\langle s_1(x, t)s_2(x', t')\rangle$ vs $\langle s_1(x, t)s_2(x', t')\rangle-\langle s_1(x, t)\rangle\langle s_2(x', t')\rangle$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, conventions, correlation-functions

The correlation function in statistical mechanics is defined in either of [two ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function_%28statistical_mechanics%29#Definitions)

1. $$g(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}', t-t') = \left\langle s_1(\mathbf{x}, t)s_2(\mathbf{x}', t') \right\rangle$$
2. $$g(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}', t-t') = \left\langle s_1(\mathbf{x}, t)s_2(\mathbf{x}', t') \right\rangle - \left\langle s_1(\mathbf{x}, t)\right\rangle\left\langle s_2(\mathbf{x}', t')\right\rangle, $$

where in both cases $s_1, s_2$ are random variables and $\left\langle \dots \right\rangle$ is the thermal average.

It seems like a matter of taste, which definition is used. I've even seen that authors decide chapter-wise which one to apply.

How is the additional term in the second variant motivated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [statistical mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function_(statistical_mechanics)) and [field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function_(quantum_field_theory)), the second type is referred to as a "connected" correlation function. You sometimes see the notation
$$
g_{\text{c}}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'},t-t') = \langle s_1(\mathbf{x},t) s_2(\mathbf{x}',t') \rangle_{\text{c}}\,\text{,}
$$
where $\langle\ldots\rangle_{\text{c}}$ indicates that the product of the averages should be subtracted. The connected correlation function corresponds to what is called the [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) in statistics.

The reason for subtracting the second term is that the expectation value of a product $\langle A B \rangle$ factorizes, i.e., $\langle AB \rangle = \langle A \rangle\langle B \rangle$, if $A$ and $B$ are [statistically independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)). So if the degrees of freedom at $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}'$ are completely uncorrelated, then the connected correlation function is zero. For example, one almost always finds that connected correlation functions vanish in the limit $\lvert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}' \rvert \rightarrow \infty$.

As Gennaro points out, the "one-point functions" $\langle s_1(\mathbf{x},t)\rangle$ and $\langle s_2(\mathbf{x}',t') \rangle$ often vanish, and so the two types of correlation function become equivalent. This usually happens for reasons of symmetry; for example, in the paramagnetic phase of the Ising model, the expectation value of the spin vanishes. In the ferromagnetic phase, on the other hand, $\langle s(\mathbf{x})\rangle = m \neq 0$ (where $m$ is the magnetization). The connected correlation function goes to zero as $\lvert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}' \rvert \rightarrow \infty$, but the other ("disconnected") correlation function does not; in fact,
$$
\langle s(\mathbf{x}) s(\mathbf{x}') \rangle \rightarrow \langle s(\mathbf{x}) \rangle \langle s(\mathbf{x}') \rangle = m^2\,\text{.}
$$

Comment: "....if and only if A and B are statistically independent.", to be precise, it is just "if" and not "if and only if"

Answer (score 2):

The general Pearson correlation between two variables is defined as
$$
\textrm{cor}(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]
$$
up to a denominator containing the standard deviations of the distributions of the two variables.

In some field theories the expectation values of the variable itself (one-point function) vanishes, therefore oftentimes the above definition reduces to the first term on the right hand side only.

Answer (score 2):

The second version is the first one *but with the observables shifted by their respective averages*:

$$\langle \tilde A\tilde B\rangle = \langle (A-\langle A\rangle)(B-\langle B\rangle)\rangle = \langle AB\rangle - \langle A\rangle\langle B\rangle$$

Oftentimes in e.g. numerical studies, it is easier to just sample the average product of the original observables $\langle AB\rangle$ and subtract the (known) product of the averages. The correlation function $\langle \tilde A\tilde B\rangle$ will typically be more interesting physically.